# How can I do Accumlative summation?

Tags: summation

In this code I do `Sum` over `r` and `x`

```
rgt[rf_, n_, m_] := ParallelSum[x r, {r, 0, rf, n}, {x, 1, 5, m}]
```

then I want to get the results for different `rf` as follows

```
Table[rgt[rf,1,1],{rf,6,20,2}]//AbsoluteTiming
{0.077568,{315,540,825,1170,1575,2040,2565,3150}}
```

Note that at each `rf` the `Sum` over `r` starts always from `0` but this can be avoided if I can just add the `Sum` of the earlier step to the next one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outer product approach:

```
rgt[rf_, n_, m_] := Accumulate@Total[
   Outer[Times, Range[0, rf, n], Range[1, 5, m]],
   {2}
   ]

rgt[20, 1, 1][[7 ;; ;; 2]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.000026, {315, 540, 825, 1170, 1575, 2040, 2565, 3150}}`

Comment: what if I have a general function, say `(Sqrt[x] + 2 r)/(r + 1)`?

Comment: @HD2006 Just put it in where `Times` is.